# Bluetooth problem!

Tags: bluetooth

I used Ubuntu 14.04 and the Bluetooth was working but I couldn't find any Bluetooth device but I thought it was from the version. Yesterday I upgraded to 15.10 but nothing changed. So I search the net and tried some commands and when I restarted my Bluetooth icon was gone and when I try to start it it says "Bluetooth disabled".[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYv3C.png)
Can you please tell me what to do?

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2  
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
    Kernel driver in use: wl

lsusb  
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp. BCM43142 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 1bcf:2b8b Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0e8f:00fb GreenAsia Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I have run

```
$dmesg | grep -i blue
```

and it said that there is no file BCM.hcd so I made a copy of my other .hcd and rename it to BCM.hcd and now I get

```
$dmesg | grep -i blue
[    8.716681] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[    8.716698] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    8.716702] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    8.716704] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    8.716709] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   10.825455] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1001 tx timeout
[   18.818540] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reading local version info failed (-110)
[   20.825861] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1001 tx timeout
[   28.819011] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reading local version info failed (-110)
[   28.838168] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   28.838172] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   28.838176] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized

$ ls -l /lib/firmware/brcm
total 9740
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  28842 Oct 23 20:59 BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 269595 Nov 24  2014 bcm4329-fullmac-4.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  96224 Dec  1  2014 bcm43xx-0.fw
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    180 Dec  1  2014 bcm43xx_hdr-0.fw
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  28842 Oct 23 20:59 BCM.hcd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 397312 Dec  1  2014 brcmfmac43143.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 385067 Oct  5 19:15 brcmfmac43143-sdio.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 348160 Nov 24  2014 brcmfmac43236b.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 455745 Dec  1  2014 brcmfmac43241b0-sdio.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 403855 Dec  1  2014 brcmfmac43241b4-sdio.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 408682 Oct  5 19:15 brcmfmac43241b5-sdio.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 479232 Sep 24 16:20 brcmfmac43242a.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 253748 Dec  1  2014 brcmfmac4329-sdio.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 222126 Dec  1  2014 brcmfmac4330-sdio.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 397378 Oct  5 19:15 brcmfmac43340-sdio.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 451566 Dec  1  2014 brcmfmac4334-sdio.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 569291 Dec  1  2014 brcmfmac4335-sdio.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 219557 Dec  1  2014 brcmfmac43362-sdio.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 493599 Sep 24 16:20 brcmfmac4339-sdio.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 488193 Oct  5 19:15 brcmfmac43455-sdio.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 591837 Oct  5 19:15 brcmfmac4354-sdio.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 557056 Sep 24 16:20 brcmfmac43569.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 593956 Oct  5 19:15 brcmfmac4356-pcie.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 550333 Sep 24 16:20 brcmfmac43570-pcie.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 595472 Oct  5 19:24 brcmfmac43602-pcie.ap.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 634267 Oct  5 19:24 brcmfmac43602-pcie.bin
```

After I removed the old files and pasted the new i get

```
$ dmesg | grep -i blue
[    8.772021] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[    8.772038] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    8.772042] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    8.772044] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    8.772052] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   10.935401] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1001 tx timeout
[   18.928513] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reading local version info failed (-110)
[   18.935776] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[   18.935780] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000
[   19.023124] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2
[   19.023130] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
[   19.968603] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   19.968606] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   19.968611] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: I followed the instructions but when I typed hex2hcd I get the .hcd file but I had to rename it myself because it said empty file. Then I turn off my laptop and then I turn it on but nothing has changed.

Comment: Try to do it more carefully. It does not create an empty file. Were there any errors?

Comment: This time I didn't get an error and I turned off/on. But the Bluetooth icon is still gone and in the Bluetooth menu it says the same thing "Bluetooth is disabled". I was able to turn on my Bluetooth until I typed
    sudo rfkill unblock all

Comment: So does it work now?

Comment: No. I just don't know what happened. Before I could turn on my Bluetooth but I couldn't find devices and the couldn't find me but it is disabled and I don't know which one of them is worse.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `dmesg | grep -i blue`

Comment: Also please add output of `ls -l /lib/firmware/brcm`

Comment: That was wrong to copy "some other file" to BCM.hcd.

Comment: Copy [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bsowlvv3f9my7kj/BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd?dl=0) file to `/lib/firmware/brcm` and remove all you did there.

Comment: Delete BCM.hcd file.

Comment: If that still does not work, then install Ubuntu 14.04.3. It will work there.

Comment: This is for sure a kernel issue.

Comment: When I was with 14.04.3 I couldn't find any device so it didn't work.

Comment: You can try to rename it to `BCM43142A0_001.001.011.0122.0126.hcd` too. I will look into the code later and see what they've done there.

Comment: It could not find devices on 14.04.3 because you did not have the firmware.

Comment: It was the same with 15.10 but then I typed 'sudo rfkill unblock hci0' and restarted and the Bluetooth was disabled.

Comment: I can't suggest anything for 15.10 at the moment. It will work for kernel 3.19.

Comment: Instead of turning off and then on my computer I restarted it and now I can turn on Bluetooth but I still can't find my phone and my phone can't find it.

Comment: I get `bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2`. Should I try to raname BCM43142A0_001.001.011.0122.0126.hcd to BCM.hcd?

Comment: I renamed it then turn off/on my laptop and now it's working. Thank you for everything.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after a kernel upgrade.
What worked for me was:

```
sudo modprobe -r btusb && sudo modprobe btusb
```

which basically unloads and loads the driver.

Comment: assuming that is the right module - there are quite a lot  of relevant ones I think: `find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -type d bluetooth -exec ls -l {} \;`