# Bluetooth Not connecting - Searching for Devices - 18.04.4 LTS

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth

My system is not detecting any Bluetooth device and i checked similar questions such as these - [Bluetooth is not working on my laptop Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1207554/bluetooth-is-not-working-on-my-laptop-ubuntu-18-04-4-lts)

None of those links helped.

I would like to know what to look for to identify whats missing at the first place. any help is appreciated

[The output of lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Btvzy.png)

dmesg | grep -i blue

```
[   23.314055] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   23.314074] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   23.314077] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   23.314079] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   23.314088] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   24.733996] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[   24.734998] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[   24.750996] Bluetooth: hci0: akash
[   24.750999] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000
[   24.943442] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2
[   24.943446] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
[   26.976024] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[   26.976976] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
[   51.085298] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   51.085300] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   51.085303] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[  105.580132] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  105.580152] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  105.580167] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[ 8328.267411] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[ 8328.268372] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[ 8328.284464] Bluetooth: hci0: akash
[ 8328.284477] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000
[ 8328.315338] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2
[ 8328.315345] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
[ 8330.341315] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[ 8330.342261] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
[ 9003.350396] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[ 9003.351370] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[ 9003.367383] Bluetooth: hci0: akash
[ 9003.367395] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000
[ 9003.367442] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2
[ 9003.367449] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
```

Comment: FYI:  A fully upgraded 18.04 will report itself as 18.04.5, so check you've applied all security fixes to your system, as you could be using an EOL kernel & be missing other security fixes.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 - I have added the link. Unfortunately i dont have the reputation yet to post images

Comment: We don't need any images. You can post terminal output as text.

Comment: Please add output of `dkms | grep -i blue`.

Comment: @pilot6 - dkms | grep -i blue ----> Error No action was specified

Comment: It was a typo `dmesg | grep -i blue`.

Comment: @pilot6 - thanks added the result to the question

Comment: So its a dupe. I gave you a link how to solve it. `brcm/BCM.hcd not found`

Comment: @pilot6 - i did check and also this - https://askubuntu.com/questions/688987/bluetooth-problem but the link is not available, the link to copy into BCM.hcd. could you tell me what to copy into BCM.hcd and what would be the destination of that file.

Comment: There are a couple of answers about how to get BCM.hcd and where to copy it. There is nothing to add. All links you give are dupes.